# The following ICU libraries were not found: -- i18n (required)

Tags: cmake, homebrew

I have to build miktex source code. I install source code from github they give me link to build it: https://miktex.org/howto/build-mac.

I follow the steps given in the link. When I run

```
cmake ../source
```

I got error:

```
INFOfribidi libs: /usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.5/lib/libfribidi.dylib
INFOfribidi incs:
/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.5/include/fribidi;/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.5/include
-- The following ICU libraries were not found:
--   i18n (required)
--   uc (required)
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
    Failed to find all ICU components (missing: ICU_INCLUDE_DIR ICU_LIBRARY _ICU_REQUIRED_LIBS_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):  
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)  
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindICU.cmake:317 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:1032 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/Users/afnisaeed/Desktop/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

**Extra information**:

```
echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/opt/icu4c:/opt/openssl:/opt/icu4c:/opt/qt:$ {brewprefix}/opt/icu4c:/opt/openssl:/opt/icu4c:/opt/qt:/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.0/
```

Comment: Have you set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable as the guide suggests? What output of `echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`?

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add the information @Tsyvarev asked for. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have lost most of the question. Do you want me to put it back how it was until 10 minutes ago?

Comment: Salmans-MBP:Desktop afnisaeed$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /opt/icu4c:/opt/openssl:/opt/icu4c:/opt/qt:$ {brewprefix}/opt/icu4c:/opt/openssl:/opt/icu4c:/opt/qt:/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.0/

Comment: i answered what @Tsyvarev asked so now what should i do...i am stuck from last 3 days on this line please help me what to do

Comment: yes put all the question back @MarkSetchell

Comment: You seem to have set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH incorrectly. It should look like `/usr/local/opt/icu4c:/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/qt:/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.0`

Comment: so can you tell me how to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH because i followed all the step 3 times

Comment: What is output of `brew --prefix` on your machine? You need to perform `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="${brewprefix}/opt/icu4c:${brewprefix}/opt/openssl:${brewprefix}/opt/icu4c:${brewprefix}/opt/qt:/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.0/"` with `${brewprefix}` replaced on that output.

Comment: Salmans-MBP:Desktop afnisaeed$ brew --prefix
/usr/local

Comment: So you need to perform `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c:/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/icu4c:${brewprefix}/opt/qt:/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.0/"`.

Comment: thank you soo much i done it .....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know nothing at all about `miktex` or `fribidi` so this may not be of any assistance at all, however your build system seems to be having difficulty finding something to do with `ICU` - whatever that is.

If you run:

```
brew info icu4c
```

it tells you a whole load of stuff about the package being *"keg-only"* which means the stuff it provides (headers and libraries) is installed, but not where any other package will find it. Then it gives you the following specific advice:

```
icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"

For pkg-config to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"
```

So, I suspect you have not done the last 2 sections, and you need to do something like:

```
export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig:"$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

---

According to comment by @IamMashed, you may also need to run:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Comment: None of these variables will help `FindICU.cmake` script to locate ICU package (`PATH` affects only on executables, LDFLAGS affects only on the linker, PKG_CONFIG_PATH helps for pkg-config, but the "Find" script doesn't use it). The guide https://miktex.org/howto/build-mac followed by the asker notes about setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, and this setting would actually help.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, cool. Like I said, I know nothing about ICU, just a little about **homebrew** and was hoping that someone who does know about it would see something and realise what is going on. Sometimes you only know half the story, but if you *"put it out there"* someone else can add the other half. So, if you want to put what you are saying as an answer, I will happily upvote it! Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know only "CMake part" of the story :) MacOS, homebrew, etc. are not things I familar with.

Comment: i have done these steps but still i am getting the error

Comment: all works...you just need to install one more thing...`brew install pkg-config`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error while trying to use find_package(ICU ...) on my Mac (installed ICU via brew). This error seems to be related to the fact the Mac already has ICU preinstalled (however not all of it's components) - that's why CMake complaints that some components are missing (ICU_INCLUDE_DIR, ICU_LIBRARY, ...).
The solution for me was to manually specify the ICU_ROOT variable in CMakeLists.txt (which targets CMake to the brew-installed ICU version instead of MacOS preinstalled version):

`set (ICU_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1)`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, postgresql 16 cause me this error. I need to use postgres 15.

Comment: Same error here. Had to install Postgres 15.5 (using asdf), version 16 raises the mentioned error.

Comment: I fixed it by setting export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig/

Detailed explanation here https://viggy28.dev/article/postgres-v16-icu-installation-issue/

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by installing the missing Debian package [libicu-dev](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libicu-dev) via:

```
apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Please note that this might also work for Ubuntu and its derivates.