# Cannot build WebKitGTK: missing ICU libraries but cannot install them

Tags: macos, gtk, webkit, webkitgtk

I'm trying to build the last release of WebKitGTK ([2.28.0](https://webkitgtk.org/releases/webkitgtk-stable.tar.xz)) following the instructions they suggest here https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk#BuildingWebKitGTKfromareleasetarball.
After extracting the downloaded tar.xz, I open that folder in a shell window and run the command:

```
cmake -DPORT=GTK -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -GNinja
```

I previously installed Ninja via Homebrew:

```
brew install ninja
```

Unfortunately, I get some errors:

```
-- The following ICU libraries were not found:
--   data (required)
--   i18n (required)
--   uc (required)
CMake Error at     /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146     (message):
  Failed to find all ICU components (missing: ICU_INCLUDE_DIR ICU_LIBRARY
  _ICU_REQUIRED_LIBS_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393     (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindICU.cmake:328     (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:28 (find_package)    
  Source/cmake/WebKitCommon.cmake:56 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:169 (include)
```

It seems like some libraries are not installed (data, i18n, uc). After trying to install *uc* via Homebrew, following the instructions in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52514452/4207800), the same errors keep showing.

I am on a Mac machine, Mojave v. 10.14.6.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, did you ever fix it?